# Extract value from ArrayType column in Scala and reshape to long

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a DataFrame that consists of Column that is ArrayType, and the array may have a different length in each row of the data. I have provide some example code below that can create some mock data with a similar structure.

You will see that for one transaction, I have a transaction ID as well as some additional data that are each stored in a "segment". Here we see one segment in which customer information is stored (always an array of length two) and we have an additional segment for each item purchase. The information about the purchased item itself is an array of varying length; the first two elements of the array will always be the ID and a name of purchased item; additional array elements may exist for color, etc. but we can ignore them in this use case.

```
val dfschema = new StructType()
  .add("transaction",
    new StructType()
      .add(
        "transaction_id",
        StringType
      )
      .add(
        "segments",
        ArrayType(
          new StructType()
            .add("segment_id",StringType)
            .add("segment_fields",ArrayType(
              StringType,
              false
            )
          ), false
        )
      )
    )


val mockdata = Seq(
  Row(
    Row(
      "2e6d57769e49ae8cb0c4105548c4389d",
      List(
        Row(
          "CustomerInformation",
          List(
            "SomeCustomerName",
            "SomeCustomerEmail"
          )
        ),
        Row(
          "ItemPurchased",
          List(
            "SomeItemID",
            "SomeItemName"
          )
        ),
        Row(
          "ItemPurchased",
          List(
            "AnotherItemID",
            "AnotherItemName",
            "ItemColor"
          )
        ),
        Row(
          "ItemPurchased",
          List(
            "YetAnotherItemID",
            "YetAnotherItemName",
            "ItemColor"
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(mockdata),
  dfschema)
```

What I want to accomplish is to convert the above into another dataframe with two columns, one for customer's name and one for item name. For the above example, it would like:

| customer.name | item.name |
| --- | --- |
| SomeCustomerName | SomeItemName |
| SomeCustomerName | AnotherItemName |
| SomeCustomerName | YetAnotherItemName |

However, I don't want to hardcode the fields of data that I am retreiving; instead, I want to write a couple functions that I you could run as part of a select command, like this:

```
df(
  select(
    get_single_subsegment("CustomerInformation", 0),
    get_repeated_subsements("ItemPurchased", 1)
  )
)
```

This way, if I choose to retrieve customer email instead of name, I just need to modify change 0 to 1 in the above. And I can even pass the index number as a variable.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As from Spark 3.0, you can use spark's built-in functions to define your two functions `get_single_subsegment` and `get_repeated_subsegments`

For `get_single_subsegment`, you can first filter your segments array by segment_id with [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#filter(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:org.apache.spark.sql.Column=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column), then get the first element of this filtered array with `getItem`, and then retrieve the element at desired index in this segment object using `getField` and `getItem`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, filter}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def get_single_subsegment(segmentId: String, index: Int): Column = {
  filter(col("transaction.segments"), c => c.getField("segment_id") === segmentId)
    .getItem(0)
    .getField("segment_fields")
    .getItem(index)
}
```

For `get_repeated_subsegments`, you first filter as in `get_single_subsegment`, but then use [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#transform(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:(org.apache.spark.sql.Column,org.apache.spark.sql.Column)=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) to extract right segment fields index for each elements of filtered array, and then [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#explode(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) this array in order to have one line by element of filtered array:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode, filter, transform}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def get_repeated_subsegments(segmentId: String, index: Int): Column = {
  explode(
    transform(
      filter(col("transaction.segments"), c => c.getField("segment_id") === segmentId)
        .getField("segment_fields"),
      c => c.getItem(index)
    )
  )
}
```

If we apply the two function defined above on your example, we get the following result:

```scala
df.select(
  get_single_subsegment("CustomerInformation", 0).as("customer_name"),
  get_repeated_subsegments("ItemPurchased", 1).as("item_name")
).show(false)

// +----------------+------------------+
// |customer_name   |item_name         |
// +----------------+------------------+
// |SomeCustomerName|SomeItemName      |
// |SomeCustomerName|AnotherItemName   |
// |SomeCustomerName|YetAnotherItemName|
// +----------------+------------------+
```

#### Bonus - extract several columns

If, as you commented, you want to extract several columns using `get_repeated_subsegments`, you need to modify `get_repeated_subsegments` in order to not perform `explode` in it but when you perform the select. You can then add several columns by using [`arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#arrays_zip(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) on arrays get by applying `get_repeated_subsegments`, as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{arrays_zip, col, explode, filter, transform}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def get_repeated_subsegments(segmentId: String, index: Int): Column = {
  transform(
    filter(col("transaction.segments"), c => c.getField("segment_id") === segmentId)
      .getField("segment_fields"),
    c => c.getItem(index)
  )
}

df.select(
    get_single_subsegment("CustomerInformation", 0).as("customer_name"),
    explode(
      arrays_zip(
        get_repeated_subsegments("ItemPurchased", 0).as("item_id"),
        get_repeated_subsegments("ItemPurchased", 1).as("item_name")
      )
    ).alias("items")
  )
  .select("customer_name", "items.*")
  .show(false)

// +----------------+----------------+------------------+
// |customer_name   |item_id         |item_name         |
// +----------------+----------------+------------------+
// |SomeCustomerName|SomeItemID      |SomeItemName      |
// |SomeCustomerName|AnotherItemID   |AnotherItemName   |
// |SomeCustomerName|YetAnotherItemID|YetAnotherItemName|
// +----------------+----------------+------------------+
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you so much! One follow up question: what if I want to extract both the item ID and the item name, and have an output with three columns (customer_name, item_id, item_name)? I tried calling the get_repeated_subsegments twice but Scala did not like that!

Comment: Updated the answer with solution to extract two columns instead of one using `get_repeated_subsegments`

Comment: Thanks again! Can you point me to documentation about the arrays_zip function somewhere online? I cannot find it on https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/index.html and while I do find some docs for pyspark, I don't find anything for Scala specifically.

Comment: Here is [the documentation for `arrays_zip`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#arrays_zip(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)